# Loop through all xls files in directory, copy range, and paste to docx file?

Tags: excel, vba, loops, ms-word, directory

I have around 500 Excel files in one directory. All files have a table on the first sheet (same size). My client wants them all in one word file. I am not an VBA expert an experimented with a code I found online. I got it so far to loop through all files in a directory. It also selects and copies the specific range. But how do I get the transfer to a word file?

Here is what I did:

```
Sub LoopAllExcelFilesInFolder()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim myPath As String
    Dim myFile As String
    Dim myExtension As String
    Dim FldrPicker As FileDialog
    'Optimize Macro Speed
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    'Retrieve Target Folder Path From User
    Set FldrPicker = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    With FldrPicker
        .Title = "Select A Target Folder"
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
        myPath = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
    End With
    'In Case of Cancel
NextCode:
    myPath = myPath
    If myPath = "" Then GoTo ResetSettings
    'Target File Extension (must include wildcard "*")
    myExtension = "*.xls"
    'Target Path with Ending Extention
    myFile = Dir(myPath & myExtension)
    'Loop through each xls files dir
    Do While myFile <> ""
        'Set variable equal to opened workbook
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=myPath & myFile)
        'Select range and copy
        Range("G10:M25").Select
        Selection.Copy
        'Save and Close Workbook
        wb.Close SaveChanges:=True
        'Get next file name
        myFile = Dir
        DoEvents
    Loop
    'Message Box when tasks are completed
    MsgBox "Task Complete!"
ResetSettings:
    'Reset Macro Optimization Settings
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: i am not much familiar with this but found this link hope it is useful http://software-solutions-online.com/vba-write-excel-values-to-word-document/

Comment: Hmm... that looks pretty good already. But I can't make it work so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code below was sourced from [here](http://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/2014/5/22/copy-paste-an-excel-table-into-microsoft-word-with-vba) and adjusted to the one you provided. You should read through the link's explanation as it answers what you asked. The only addition I did to the code below was to put a counter (`i`) so you can add the tables in the word document as you cycle through them.

```
Sub LoopAllExcelFilesInFolder()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim myPath As String
Dim myFile As String
Dim myExtension As String
Dim FldrPicker As FileDialog

Dim tbl As Excel.Range
Dim WordApp As Word.Application
Dim myDoc As Word.Document
Dim WordTable As Word.Table

Dim i As Long

'Optimize Macro Speed
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

'Retrieve Target Folder Path From User
Set FldrPicker = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)

With FldrPicker
    .Title = "Select A Target Folder"
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
    myPath = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
End With

'In Case of Cancel
NextCode:
myPath = myPath
If myPath = "" Then GoTo ResetSettings

'Target File Extension (must include wildcard "*")
myExtension = "*.xls"

'Target Path with Ending Extention
myFile = Dir(myPath & myExtension)

On Error Resume Next

'Is MS Word already opened?
Set WordApp = GetObject(class:="Word.Application")

'Clear the error between errors
Err.Clear

'If MS Word is not already open then open MS Word
If WordApp Is Nothing Then Set WordApp = CreateObject(class:="Word.Application")

'Handle if the Word Application is not found
If Err.Number = 429 Then
    MsgBox "Microsoft Word could not be found, aborting."
    GoTo EndRoutine
End If

On Error GoTo 0

'Make MS Word Visible and Active
WordApp.Visible = True
WordApp.Activate

'Create a New Document
Set myDoc = WordApp.Documents.Add


'Loop through each xls files dir
i = 1
Do While myFile <> ""
'Set variable equal to opened workbook
Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=myPath & myFile)

'Assign range and Copy
Set tbl = Range("G10:M25")
tbl.Copy

'Paste Table into MS Word
myDoc.Paragraphs(i).Range.PasteExcelTable _
                    LinkedToExcel:=False, _
                    WordFormatting:=False, _
                    RTF:=False

'Autofit Table so it fits inside Word Document
Set WordTable = myDoc.Tables(i)
WordTable.AutoFitBehavior (wdAutoFitWindow)

i = i + 1 'Incrementing paragraph and table number

'Save and Close Workbook
wb.Close SaveChanges:=True

'Get next file name
myFile = Dir

DoEvents

Loop

'Message Box when tasks are completed
MsgBox "Task Complete!"

ResetSettings:
'Reset Macro Optimization Settings
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```